# How does Zypper find the required packages in the repository?

Tags: package-management, opensuse, zypper

When we use `zypper install <package_name>`, zypper installs the package along with its dependencies.
What exactly is happening in the background?
Are there any ways to obtain the URL of a specific package(or rpm) using zypper(or any other tool)?

Comment: `$ man zypper` https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Zypper_manual_(plain) .... Standards RepoInfo https://en.opensuse.org/openSUSE:Standards_RepoInfo ... *Your* repo : `/etc/zypp/repos.d/` ( The *.repo files use the same format as yum/dnf in Fedora: http://linux.die.net/man/5/yum.conf → section "[repository] OPTIONS".)

Comment: I looked up both of the links that you have provided. But I couldn't find a direct way to find the URL to a specific package or rpm like yumdownloader provides. Isn't there such an option in Zypper?

Comment: `zypper se name` ( or part of name ). .... `# zypper install --download-only [package-name]` .... I don't know anything like {yum-utils, yumdownloader --urls [name]}. https://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/leap/reference/html/book.opensuse.reference/cha.sw_cl.html .... Suggest : Get the url´s from the repo site http://download.opensuse.org/

Comment: I'm trying to do it programmatically. So manually going to download.opensuse.org to find the URL won't help. Anyway, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could grep the zypper.log to retrieve the RPM's URL:

```
leap15:~ # zypper in xeyes
[...]
```

Depending on your search string you could find the URL to the respective RPM:

```
leap15:~ # grep 'http://download.opensuse.org' /var/log/zypper.log | grep xeyes
2018-10-15 11:37:16 <1> leap15(15814) [zypp++] MediaCurl.cc(doGetFileCopyFile):1499 URL: http://download.opensuse.org/distribution/leap/15.0/repo/oss/x86_64/xeyes-1.1.1-lp150.1.3.x86_64.rpm
```